# WPF User control fill width of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have run into a snag with User Controls.  I'm trying to get my custom User Control to fill a `ListBox` width, even when the `ListBox` is resized with the containing window.

Now, being new to WPF (relatively speaking), I may be doing something quite wrong. But what I have attempted to do is something like the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomControl">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <uc:CustomControl />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="Container" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomControl}" Padding="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
</Grid>
```

The User Control looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControll"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:DataConverters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="50"  MinWidth="250" Background="#FFACA4A4" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid x:Name="CompleteBtn">     
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Image Source="img" MouseDown="CompleteBtn_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Complete Task" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

problem is, this will not `Stretch` to fill the width of the `ListBox`.

I have also tried using `Width="{Binding ElementName=Container, Path=ActualWidth}"` on the User Control itself, but this causes the element to be wider than the `ListBox` if a margin is added, causing the horizontal bar to appear. in addition to that, if I add enough of these elements to cause the vertical scroll bar to appear, it covers the User Control slightly.

My question is thus, How do I get a User Control to fill the width of a list box with a specified margin on either side (may vary in size) without the horizontal bar appearing and that will not be covered by a vertical bar?

Comment: Avoid using `<StackPanel>` in the `CustomControl`.

Comment: Try define `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Comment: @Lei What is the difference between setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and defining a `DataTemplate` when using a User Control? Is my User Control not the template?

Answer (score 3):

simple way:using Horizontal**Content**Alignment="Stretch" 
it should work

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomControl">

            <loc:UserControl1 />

    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="Container"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Margin="5,5,5,5"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomControl}"
             Padding="0"
             Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
             UseLayoutRounding="True" />
</Grid>
```

let me know if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomControl">
    <Grid>
        <uc:CustomControl />
    <Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` in your `DataTemplate`